# How did this user replace the body with a "...", but not replace the body at all?

Tags: bug, question-lists

As you can see, the body of this question below is a "..."

[image]

But clicking the question leads to this.

[image]

Searching up the question yields the body as well.

[image]

How did the user get a ... as the question body?

Comment: Can you link the question?

Comment: I think it was just that the system messed up trying to create the excerpt there. The ellipsis is that there is more text that follows. For whatever reason, it didn't pull anything from the body to display *before* the ellipsis. I don't think the user did anything themselves.

Comment: @Myst [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/taming-the-beast) (it is forth on home page now).

Comment: Hah. Yeah, looks like something that's probably on our end.

Comment: I thought this has always happened if the question starts off with code, quoted text or an image? Although it would be better if it just skipped over it.